# Can I capture STDOUT write events from a process in perl?

Tags: perl, ipc, stdout

I need (would like?) to spawn a slow process from a web app using a [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion) queue.

The process - a [GLPK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit) solver - can run for a long time but generates progress output.

I'd like to capture that output as it happens and write it to somewhere (database? log file?) so that it can be played back to the user as a status update inside the web app.

Is that possible? I have no idea (hence no code).

I was exploring [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) - the simplicity of it is nice but I can't tell if it can track write events upon writing.

Comment: How do you launch the child? With IPC::Run, you can provide callback subs. With IPC::Run, you can also use pseudo-ttys to fool the child into flushing its output more often if it normally buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic way is to use pipe open, where you [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a pipe to a process that gets forked. Then the `STDOUT` from the child is piped to the filehandle in the parent, or the parent pipes to its `STDIN`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @cmd = qw(ls -l .);  # your command

my $pid = open(my $fh, '-|', @cmd)   // die "Can't open pipe from @cmd: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print;
}

close $fh or die "Error closing pipe from @cmd: $!";
```

This way the parent receives child's `STDOUT` right as it is emitted.<sup>†</sup>

There is a bit more that you can do with error checking, see the man page, [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html), and [`$?` in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3f).  Also, install a handler for `SIGPIPE`, see [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) and [`%SIG` in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG).

There are modules that make it far easier to run and manage external commands and, in particular, check errors.  However, [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) and [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) use files to transfer the external program's streams.

On the other hand, the [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) gives you far more control and power.

To have code executed ["*... each time some data is read from the child*"](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run#Redirection-Operators) use a callback

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Run qw(run);

my @cmd = ( 
    'perl', 
    '-le', 
    'STDOUT->autoflush(1); for (qw( abc def ghi )) { print; sleep 1; }'
);

run \@cmd, '>', sub { print $_[0] };
```

Once you use `IPC::Run` a lot more is possible, including better error interrogation, setting up pseudo tty for the process, etc.  For example, using `>pty>` instead of `>` sets up a terminal-like environment so the external program that is run may turn back to line buffering and provide more timely output.  If demands on how to manage the process grow more complex then work will be easier with the module.

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments, including the demo `@cmd`.

---

<sup>†</sup> To demonstrate that the parent receives child's `STDOUT` as it is emitted use a command that emits output with delays. For example, instead of `ls -l` above use

```
my @cmd = (
    'perl', 
    '-le', 
    'STDOUT->autoflush(1); for (qw( abc def ghi )) { print; sleep 1; }'
);
```

This Perl one-liner prints words one second apart, and that is how they wind up on screen.